# Java difference between AtomicInteger addAndGet() and getAndAdd()?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the `addAndGet` and `getAndAdd` methods of `Atomic*` classes like `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong`?

The Javadoc doesn't list any difference:

> `addAndGet(long delta)`
>   Atomically adds the given value to the current value.
>
> `getAndAdd(long delta)`
>   Atomically adds the given value to the current value.

Comment: Pre-increment and Post-increment

Comment: Right there in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#addAndGet(int)) Returns:
the updated value   vs Returns:
the previous value

Comment: ++i / i++, that's the equivalent :)

Comment: One of them first gets and then adds. The other first adds then gets.

Comment: "does not show any research effort" seems applicable.

Comment: The research conducted doesn't show any obvious difference, hence the question.

Comment: @NathanHughes I saw your answer below, is it `groovysh`?  It looks really amazing to interact with java code directly

Comment: Downvoting == I know the answer and you don't lol. Way to go SO. You're not exactly improving with time...

Comment: @haifzhan: yes. groovysh has its quirks but it is nice to be able to use a repl with java. there's also groovyconsole. lots of jvm languages (scala, clojure, jython, jruby, etc.) have a comparable feature, also java may get something like it eventually.

Comment: @NathanHughes Good to know that, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference is in what they return, in analogy to the pre-increment (e.g. `++i`) and post-increment (e.g. `i++`) operators.

[The `addAndGet` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#addAndGet-int-):

> Returns:
>
> the updated value

[The `getAndAdd` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndAdd-int-):

> Returns:
>
> the previous value

Answer (score 4):

As answered already in comments: This is pre- and post-increment. Try it out:

```
groovy:000> import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*
===> java.util.concurrent.atomic.*
groovy:000> a = new AtomicLong(0)
===> 0
groovy:000> a.addAndGet(1)
===> 1
groovy:000> a
===> 1
groovy:000> a.getAndAdd(2)
===> 1
groovy:000> a
===> 3
```